# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectors' of null After Upgrading to Angular v9

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded my Angular app from v7 to v8, and then v8 to v9. Locally it works perfectly if I run `ng serve`. But when I run a production build, `ng build --prod`, and deploy the app I get an error in the console of the application:

[image: TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectors' of null]

I can't find anything helpful to solve the issue. I did find a couple other people who had this issue, but no solutions. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the prod and dev objects are same in angular.json file? Otherwise check the main.ts file.

Comment: Do you have strict type checking enabled in the config? If not, try that and you might be able to see where the problem originates during developement. I'd guess that at some point some types actually need to be `| null` + checks.

Comment: So there are no specifics given when copying all the production settings to the development mode, but the only thing that got it working there was turning off aot and buildOptimizer. If those are both set to false, then the `ng serve` works locally. Trying it now to make sure it works when deployed.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check your "@angular/core" version and your "angular-devkit/build-angular" version.In my case they were in a different version, and after i fix that it works for me.

Angular 11:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "11.2.5",
    ......

 "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.1102.5",
    "@angular/cli": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "11.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "11.2.5",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to rebuild the project again. It started working